# Invalid Data Source in QGIS

Tags: qgis, data-source

I bought a new laptop recently. However, when I tried to load shapefiles or geopackage, it will always return an error message:

```
Invalid Data Source:  world-administrative-boundaries.zip is not a valid or recognized data source
```

This is strange as I am able to load the same shapefile in my old laptop. Thus I am sure there is nothing wrong with my data.

Comment: What version of QGIS are you using and on what operating system?  I think the default install of current versions (mine is 3.28) will see the contents of a zip file but there is a setting you should check to be sure.  It's in Settings - Options - Data Source - Data Source Handling - Scan for contents of compressed files.  Basic scan should work as well as Full, but the drop down can be set to No which would be a problem for you.

Comment: possibly to do with the version of zip you have installed on your computer and set as default. I know ive had issues in the past with files zipped by the windows zip facility, but then I would zip them with 7-zip and they would work. so maybe try unzipping the files first just to confirm their contents and this may confirm the zip theory.